# Set all empty strings to NULL in all records of all tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to update all records with an empty string in all columns of all tables in PostgreSQL. Is there a way to do this with a query? Or at least how to query for all columns that don't have a NOT NULL constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit the information_schema like this

```
select * 
from information_schema.columns
where is_nullable = 'YES';
```

From that data you can generate yourself update statements for all the tables and columns.

Comment: In the future you may want to put a constraint on these columns to keep them from being allowed to be empty strings.

Comment: @StarShip3000 this is data brought in from another database. No foreign keys, no constraints of any sort.....

Comment: You may want to filter on a specific database and namespace:

`select table_name, column_name from information_schema.columns where is_nullable = 'YES' and table_schema = '<name_space>' and table_catalog = '<db_name>'`. After having this result in a text file, you could replace the line start by `SELECT count(*) from`, the pipe separator by `where` and the line end by `::text = '';`. This will give you select commands to run to identify tables with empty strings